# Scheduling Jupyter Notebooks to run one after the other

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have 9 jupyter notebooks in Anaconda that are parsing large txt files, validating their data and providing validation output in 9 different excel workbooks to end users. With my algo being now complete, I need to take all these notebooks into production and they need to be run in a particular order one after the other without having the user need to click the Run button anywhere (they have no idea of Anaconda or Jupyter).
My question is - is there an option of designing a workflow in Anaconda itself which will enable this? Or any other external option to make these Jupyters run?

I tried using Jupyter Labs but to no avail.

Comment: [Jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) to execute the notebooks controlled by [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to control the workflow can handle this and these are well integrated with the Python/Jupyter ecosystem. Snakemake can monitor when you update any file in the workflow chain and run the approrpriate process to update all downstream files as well. Importantly, Snakemake tracks things and only processes the rules to update the downstream files affected by any upstream changes and not all the files.

Comment: And more pertinent for the title of your post [Introducing Jupyter Scheduler](https://blog.jupyter.org/introducing-jupyter-scheduler-f9e82676c388) by the Open Source Jupyter team at AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello have you tried to automate the execution of Jupyter notebooks throught Papermill? You can use it to set up your jobs in a specific order, one approach is to use a workflow management tool or create a script that executes the notebooks sequentially. You can try Papermill that is a Python library that allows you to parameterize and execute Jupyter notebooks.You can define the execution order of the notebooks by creating a script that uses Papermill to run each notebook one after the other. You can pass input parameters and output paths between the notebooks as needed.
regards
juliano

Comment: Everytime I try to install Papermill it gives me the below error in Aanaconda Prompt:

Command ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\LOCAL_~1\Temp\pip-build-env-lk5_g08r --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://kumarjit.das@email.com:AP9RHWoSSZzS2gJfTueSaK8tqV3@artifactory.intranet.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-all/simple/ --trusted-host artifactory.intranet.com -- setuptools>=43 wheel" failed with error code 2 in None

Comment: Can you help? I have no issues with access and have anaconda installed already.

Comment: Hi @dskmrjt 
pip install papermill has generated the mentioned error ? 
What is the version that you are trying to install ? 2.4.0 ?

Comment: Ok, so I had to create an environment in Anaconda outside of the base environment to be able to install papermill which is done now. Thanks all for your help!